# What is the optimal Weapon + Perk combo for Damage Per Second + Cheap Ammo in Fallout 76?

Tags: fallout-76

My current Fallout 76 character is specialised in semi-automatic rifles with stealth damage (Marksmen + Sandman). Which is great for general gameplay but is completely overwhelmed for multiple Scorchbeasts & the Scorchbeast Queen.

For DPS spamming I've been using an auto grenade launcher (with Demolition Expert V) but the ammo is quite "expensive" with 3 x springs per 9 x 40mm grenade (with the Ammosmith II perk). Springs are difficult to scavenge in large numbers & expensive to buy at 151 caps x 20 springs.

So I've been going through [the wiki weapons table](https://fallout.fandom.com/wiki/Fallout_76_weapons) trying to work out a better loadout for fighting Scorchbeast & can't find anything better than the auto grenade launcher.

However, if feels like I'm missing something obvious (more/ different Perks? easy source of springs?) & was wondering if anyone has crunched the numbers properly to identify the optimal weapon + perk combo for maximum DPS, hopefully with cheap/ plentiful ammo.

Comment: I can't promise anything about optimal weapons due to the regular nerfs and buffs, but springs can be farmed from the National Isolated Radio Array

Comment: At the moment the current consensus on fo76 reddit seems to be that for boss events (and the new Daily Ops) you mostly have to have a heavy gun, with yes, a decent legendary effect and/or Prime receiver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of now - on Fallout 76 Patch 11 - the current meta is to use weapons with the bloodied legendary effect. I am particularly partial to a bloodied Handmade Rifle, as are many other players.

Refer to [this post](https://www.reddit.com/r/fo76/comments/ciib8e/powerful_and_high_survivability_bloodied/) and [this special build](https://nukesdragons.com/fallout76/perks?v=1&s=3f245cf&d=la2lr1l71l12lu2l31am2ar1a21ao0a02a30ir2ib1c72eh0eu0p02pd2pk2pp2pl2sg2&w=&n=&m=012589acef) for a general guide of what to use. Lone Wanderer is critical if playing alone, any other perks to boost gun damage are important too.

As a general guide though, the gun alone isn't what gets you to the optimal build, the legendary effect on it is. Anything bloodied is going to be good. Two-shot and explosive has been recently nerfed, but a two-shot explosive handmade is now much cheaper due to the nerf and still very effective.

As I said in the comments, you can farm springs from clipboards in the National Isolated Radio Array. Clipboards are abundant there, I'd recommend setting up camp nearby.